# Looking for a gem like websnap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm looking for a gem similar to [websnap](https://github.com/siuying/websnap/) that basically takes a snapshot of a website. Websnap is great but it generates a rather large file (12MB+). It also takes an screenshot of the entire webpage which can cause the image to be quite tall when all I basically need is the top x number of pixels of the website.

Answer (score 0):

Using websnap, you could pass in some options to change quality of image and screenshots style. For what I see in the code, this would be used when calling wkhtmltoimg.

wkhtmltoimg supports the "--quality" parameter, so if you try the following you could decrease image size by downgraiding quality. You can also use the "--height" parameter to specify a fixed height for the image.

```
snap = WebSnap::Snapper.new('http://google.com', :format => 'jpg', 
            :quality => '30', :height => '600')
```

You can see some examples in the gem's spec [here](https://github.com/siuying/websnap/blob/master/spec/websnap_spec.rb)